# How to find object relations with the schema builder?

Tags: custom-object, relationships, standard-objects, schema-builder

If I have 5 objects that are interrelated. How do i find their relationship (parent to child or child to parent) using the schema builder ?  As of now i can see the relationship chart only if i know the objects already

Comment: Please do try to find relevant tags for your question. This will help attract people with the right knowledge to your question, i've gone ahead and done that for you in this case.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you can only manually add objects to the canvas in Schema Builder - there's no way to 'spider' relationships automatically.

There's an idea on IdeaExchange for this feature:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aL4rAAE